# how to check 2 conditions using while on linux

Tags: linux

when i do:

```
while [ $choice != 'X' ]
do
```

it works but when i do

```
while [ $choice != 'x' ] || [ $choice != 'X' ]
do
```

none of them work.

Any idea?

Comment: "with bash" would probably be a better wording (this is bash, right?) than "under linux".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man test`

> ```
>  EXPRESSION1 -o EXPRESSION2
>       either EXPRESSION1 or EXPRESSION2 is true
> ```

```
 while [ $choice != 'x' -o $choice != 'X' ]
```

Note that this expression is always true, do you want `and`: `-a`?

If you replace `||` with `&&` it will work too..

Comment: || can be used instead of -o. The only problem is that the expression always true.

Comment: if [ $choice == 'r' ] || [ $choice == 'R' ] woked that is why i tried to do the same thing. Thanks alot. it works perfect